# Created columns are not showing in the page detail form of web page in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, properties, pages

I need to add a date and time type properties and change it via page details form of web page.

When I add properties in the Pages library, it is not shown in the page details form of web page in the properties list.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out an answer.

**Creating custom properties works** only **with parent web site**. Maybe I made an error when I created a subsidiary web site (yes, I forgot to mention it in the question, I hadn't any idea that it was important).